# Continuity of composition of continuous functions in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are continuous applications between metric spaces, then $g\circ f$ is continuous.

I prove this statement only for a point $x_0\in X$ (it's sufficient).

Let $x_0\in X$.

Because $f$ is continuous in $x_0$,

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\quad \exists \delta_f>0$ such that $ d_X(x,x_0)<\delta_f \Longrightarrow d_Y\left(f(x),f(x_0)\right)<\varepsilon$

but $g$ is continuous in $y_0=f(x_0)$, so,

$\exists \delta_g>0$ such that  $d_Y(y,y_0)<\delta_g \Longrightarrow d_Z\left(g(y),g(y_0)\right)<\varepsilon$

Let's consider $g\circ f :X\to Z$ and define $\delta=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$.

So, because $\delta\leq \delta_f$, we have:

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\quad  d_X(x,x_0)<\delta \Longrightarrow d_Y\left(f(x),f(x_0)\right)<\varepsilon$

and, because $\delta\leq \delta_g$, we have:

$\forall \varepsilon>0, \quad d_Y(y,y_0)<\delta \Longrightarrow d_Z\left(g(y),g(y_0)\right)<\varepsilon$

So, $\forall \varepsilon>0,\quad \exists \delta>0$ such that $ d_X(x,x_0)<\delta \Longrightarrow d_Z\left(g\left(f(x)\right), g\left(f(x_0)\right)\right)<\varepsilon$.
Then, $g\circ f$ is continuous in $x_0$.

Does it works?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. You would want to use the $f$'s $\epsilon$ as the $\delta_g$.

Comment: I believe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741661/proof-of-the-continuity-of-composite-functions-in-metric-spaces) explains what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Note that you can prove this result rather easily for general topological spaces $X, Y, Z$.